# How to add a new column to a dataframe from re.search output?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to extract numbers from a column in a dataframe using re.search function to look for numeric characters then transform from `"14 mins 16 secs"` to  `856` (seconds). and I want the output from `re.search` to be stored in a new column.

This is a subset of the current data frame. The column I want to change is named `'Time taken'`:

[image: Data Frame]

I am trying with `re.search` and currently it outputs the converted minutes seconds as seconds, but I am not able to store the output in a new column...

```
MS_REGEX = re.compile('^(\d+)\smins\s(\d+)\ssecs$')
M_REGEX = re.compile('^(\d+)\smins$')
MSEC_REGEX = re.compile('^(\d+)\smins\s(\d+)\ssec$')

def total_seconds(time_col):
        found = MS_REGEX.search(time_col)
        if found:
            return 60 * int(found.group(1)) + int(found.group(2))

        found = M_REGEX.search(time_col)
        if found:
            return 60 * int(found.group(1))


        found = MSEC_REGEX.search(time_col)
        if found:
            return 60 * int(found.group(1)) + int(found.group(2))


for elements in df['Time taken']:
     print(total_seconds(elements))
```

My output shows the new_column as NaN values...

[image: Output]

What I want is something like this:
[image: Desired Output]

Comment: Why are you defining the same variable twice? Both `MS_REGEX` and `MSEC_REGEX` are the same.

Comment: hi, it is not the same, one pattern looks for x mins y secs/  the other looks for x mins y sec  (it is missing an s at the end... that is why I created a new pattern)

Answer (score 2):

Pandas already has a built-in method to parse a series of strings to a series of timedelta objects, [`pandas.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html).

However for this to work, you first need to slightly change your strings, so the automatic parser works. `"mins"` needs to be replaced with `"min"` and `"secs"` and `"sec"` with `"s"`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Time taken": ["14 mins 16 secs", "17 mins 54 secs", "18 mins", "18 mins 1 sec"]})
df["Time taken"] = df["Time taken"].str.replace("mins", "min").str.replace("secs|sec", "s")
df["time"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["Time taken"]).dt.total_seconds()
df
#     Time taken    time
# 0  14 min 16 s   856.0
# 1  17 min 54 s  1074.0
# 2       18 min  1080.0
# 3   18 min 1 s  1081.0
```

Comment: You should replace `sec|secs` with `secs|sec`, otherwise you get `ss` instead of `s`, and then `to_timedelta` will raise an exception.

Comment: @RolandSmith True, I made that change without trying it again, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

One of possible options is to **extract** sequences of digits into
a temporary DataFrame:

```
tm = df['Time taken'].str.extract('(?P<mins>\d+)\D+(?P<secs>\d+)?')\
    .fillna(0).astype('int')
```

Note that column names are taken from capturing group names.

*Fillna* is required to change `NaN` values for missing seconds into zeroes.
And finally *astype* is needed to override the default type of *object*
(extracted sequences are strings).

Then you can set the `time` column using a numeric formula:

```
df['time'] = tm.mins * 60 + tm.secs
```

And finally you should delete the temporary DataFrame using `del tm`.

The advantage of my solution is that `Time taken` column is not changed.